Calculate the value of the expression $\sin^2 HAB+ \sin^2 HAD+ \sin^2HAA'$.
The problem
Let $ABCDA'B'C'D'$ be a rectangular parallelepiped and H the orthocenter of the triangle $A'BD$. Calculate the value of the expression $\sin^2 HAB+ \sin^2 HAD+ \sin^2HAA'$.
my idea
drawing

First I wanted to locate the position of point $H$ so I drew $AX \perp BD$ and $BY \perp A'D$. Applying the theorem of the three perpendiculars, we conclude that $BY\perp A'D$ and $A'X \perp BD $, so both are heights in the triangle $A'BD$ and intersect in H.
Then I drew $HZ\perp AX, AA'\perp AX=> AA' || HZ, AA' \perp ABCD=> HZ \perp ABCD$
I don't know what to do forward... I thought of using the golden formula: $\sin^2+\cos^2=1$
I hope one of you can help me! Thanks!

Ever heard about direction cosines?

@Intelligentipauca Nope

If you regard $AA'$, $AB$, $AD$ as coordinate axes, then your three angles are the direction angles of line $AH$, hence the sum of the squares of their cosines is $1$ and the sum of the squares of their sines is $3-1=2$, for ANY point $H$.

Let $H$ be ANY point inside the parallelepiped (but it could even be outside) and let $H_1$, $H_2$, $H_3$ be its projections onto lines $AB$, $AD$, $AA'$ respectively. Then we have:
$$
\cos\angle HAB={AH_1\over AH},\quad
\cos\angle HAD={AH_2\over AH},\quad
\cos\angle HAA'={AH_3\over AH}
$$
and
$$
\cos^2\angle HAB+\cos^2\angle HAD+\cos^2\angle HAA'=
{AH_1^2+AH_2^2+AH_3^2\over AH^2}=1.
$$
Hence:
$$
\begin{align}
\sin^2\angle HAB+\sin^2\angle HAD+\sin^2\angle HAA'&=
3-(\cos^2\angle HAB+\cos^2\angle HAD+\cos^2\angle HAA')\\
&=2.
\end{align}
$$
EDIT.
Here's an explanation for $AH_1^2+AH_2^2+AH_3^2= AH^2$ (see figure below):
$$
AH^2=AK^2+HK^2=AH_1^2+AH_2^2+AH_3^2.
$$


Thanks so much for  your answer! May I ask how you knew that $$
{AH_1^2+AH_2^2+AH_3^2\over AH^2}=1.
$$ Is there any way of explaining it without vectors or functions, I didn't learned about them yet... And also, which parallelogram are you talking about, maybe you meant triangle...

It's just Pythagoras Theorem... The other was a typo, corrected now.

@IONELABUCIU See my edit.


Hint: As you can see in picture triangle A'BD is equilateral and together with vertex A makes a pyramid AH is the altitude of the pyramid and also it is the altitude of three equal triangles ABY,AGD and AA'X. Let the edge of the cube is unity , then find the measures of angles required. You have to find the angles about $55^o$ and the sum S is about 2.
Update: If the construction is a rectangular cube then the angles depend on the ratio of height to the edge of the base. In the following figures :Height(h)=12 and AB(a)=3, that is $\frac ha=3 $. The altitude of the pyramid meets the plane of the isosceles triangle A'BD at the point of intersection of the medians of triangle. The angles are:
$\alpha=\beta=180-107.5=72.5$
$\gamma=180-154.8=25.2$
$S=sin^2\alpha +\sin^2 \beta+sin^2 \gamma=2$
That is S is constant for any value of altitude.



I dont understand wdym. A'BD would be equilateral only if we would have a cube.... Correct me if I'm wrong

@IONELABUCIU, You are right. Sorry I did not notice the statement. However the method is similar. You can find AH as the distance of A from plane ABD.

Can you pls post an answer with this, I don't understand...
